# Methods for decreasing exported .wav file size

Tags: sound-design, audacity, wav, export, filesize

I am working on sound project using Audacity.

Are there any methods for decreasing the exported .wav file size without damaging the sound quality? e.g. combining all track to a single one and then export the file.

The current settings are 44100Hz @ 16bit, I wish to keep it like that and yet get a minimal size .wav file.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe just compress them after exporting?.. write a script which compresses every file that goes to a set directory?, Not knowing what kind of sound you export, you could also export small loops that reconstruct the initial wav when you just put them side by side.. just some ideas..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAV is a lossless raw format, so the short answer to your question is no.

The only way to reduce the filesize is to :

- use a different export format, or
- shorten the length of the project.

There are various lossless compression tools available to you such as WAVPack, FLAC.
The lossy compression tools that could be considered are aac or mp3.

Comment: Making a mono .wav file instead of stereo will make the resulting file half the size, but that almost certainly qualifies as "damaging the sound quality" as excluded in the question.